# How can I use World Weather online to create a dynamic weather widget?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, widget, weather-api

Is there any way to dynamically fetch weather data from World Weather Online in order to create a weather widget.

I tried to add web service reference but I'm not getting any clue what URL should be used to load xml data.

Is there any way to load data using service reference.

I want to do something like in the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jK-cWZQqeJw

But I don't want to use the mentioned website because it works only with zip code.

I want it to work with city/place name.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Their recent blog [post](http://blog.worldweatheronline.com/2015/02/05/getting-started-world-weather-online-api-php/) shows how to get and use the data from their API in PHP, it should be very easy to convert this to ASP. Generally to read data from any external API you would use something like Curl.

To get the API to specifically return XML you just need to add a format parameter like this:

```
 https://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?q=new+york&num_of_days=5&key=a7e124b57d3e3d3671960ddcbe467&tp=24&format=xml
```

Here is the [documentation](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/api/docs/local-city-town-weather-api.aspx) link